# Create an automatic union between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have 14 tables which have as a name "something_order_items".

These tables have most of the fields in common but not all of them.

I would like to make a UNION with all these tables and, if some of them don't have a particular field, set it as null.

Currently I'm doing it manually

```
SELECT 
field_1,
field_2,
field_3,
field_4,
NULL as field_5,
field_6
...
FROM table_1_order_items
UNION
SELECT 
field_1,
field_2,
NULL as field_3,
field_4,
field_5,
field_6
...
FROM table_2_order_items
UNION
...
SELECT 
field_1,
field_2,
field_3,
field_4,
field_5,
NULL as field_6
...
FROM table_14_order_items
```

Is it possible to make it automatically?

Comment: Create VIew with these tables union and start using view directly.

Comment: To do this literally as what you likely have in mind, you would need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why you have a lot of similar tables? Combine them into one, add a column which identifies the group, maybe partition by it.

Comment: If these tables structures are completely similar and they uses MyISAM engine then you may create "supertable" using MERGE engine.

Comment: @Akina I don't make the DB. I just work on it.